# Types with min length and max length in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a simple way to do something like this?

```
import Data.Int (Int64)



class BoundedLen a where
  minLen :: Int64
  maxLen :: Int64
  len    :: a -> Int64



data LenError = TooShort | TooLong



validateLen :: BoundedLen a => a -> Either LenError a
validateLen x
    | minLen > len x = Left TooShort
    | maxLen < len x = Left TooLong
    | otherwise      = Right x
```

That code won't work because of the ambiguity check.

I want to do this to validate user input of any kind, but maybe i'm going too far?

Comment: A poor mans solution could be to define `minLen` and `maxLen` as `a -> Int64`, define them like `minLen _ = 12`, and then call it with that argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modern way is to turn on a bunch of extensions: `ScopedTypeVariables, AmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications`.

```
validateLen :: forall a. BoundedLen a => a -> Either LenError a
validateLen x
    | minLen @a > len x = Left TooShort
    | maxLen @a < len x = Left TooLong
    | otherwise         = Right x
```

Alternatively, you can add a dummy argument to your methods, to remove the ambiguity.

```
class BoundedLen a where
  minLen :: a -> Int64  -- the argument is not really used
  maxLen :: a -> Int64  -- the argument is not really used
  len    :: a -> Int64

validateLen :: BoundedLen a => a -> Either LenError a
validateLen x
    | minLen x > len x = Left TooShort
    | maxLen x < len x = Left TooLong
    | otherwise        = Right x
```

This is not too bad here, but passing `x` only to disambiguate the type feels quite unnatural, since the value of `x` is irrelevant.

One can also use a proxy, as in

```
class BoundedLen a where
  minLen :: proxy a -> Int64
  maxLen :: proxy a -> Int64
  len    :: a -> Int64

validateLen :: forall a. BoundedLen a => a -> Either LenError a
validateLen x
    | minLen (Proxy :: Proxy a) > len x = Left TooShort
    | maxLen (Proxy :: Proxy a) < len x = Left TooLong
    | otherwise        = Right x
```

but this is more cumbersome to use than the first alternative, and still requires `ScopedTypeVariables` (or even more code). I don't recommend to use proxies.

Comment: It's easy to avoid `ScopedTypeVariables` in your last example; e.g. replace `(Proxy :: Proxy a)` with just `[x]`. It's even less cumbersome than the "modern" way in some respects (e.g. no `forall` needed).

Comment: @DanielWagner I partly agree, but I really don't like that solution. Passing `[x]` would make me thing that its value matters, when it does not. I prefer to pass real proxies to make my intent clear -- so much that i would use `Proxy a` instead of `proxy a` in the method signatures. To remove the extension, I'd refine a global `proxyOf :: a -> Proxy a` and exploit that. IMO, it should be defined in the library along `reproxy` and friends. Or better, (IMO) the whole library should be scrapped, since there's no more need for proxies.